# SQL Server: single usermode 

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I had an issue with SQL sysadmin accounts and SA disabled.

I wanted to recreate the sysadmin account using single user mode.

`-m'SQLCMD'` activated the single usermode on one of the SQL Server instances service (one of the named instance).

The problem is, when I am trying to log on sqlcmd, I am get the error message:

> `Login failed`, Server is in single usermode only one administrator can connect at this time.

I stopped all the services, leaving only me logged on. Disabled even tcp, but still I get the same error.

How do I find out if any account is trying to log on, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use the lower case `-m"sqlcmd"`.

The -m option would do a string match on the client name.

This is how microsoft recommends that it be used.

Refer: [Start SQL Server in Single-User Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188236.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the reply . I used lowecase -m : it is in single usermode . but the problem i have is i couldnot login to sqlcmd  .. error message : msg18461,level14 state 1, loging failed for the user ,Server is in single usermode .Only one administrator can connect at this time .

Comment: Not the lower case -m but the lower case "sqlcmd". If that does not work, you have another program connecting as "sqlcmd". Maybe using management studio will help. Setting for that is there in the refered link.

Comment: Even the management studio same error : I could not figure out this error . I stopped all the sql services except sqlserver service . there is no other users log in aswell .. but it wont let me log in .. i wonder why

Comment: Well, if you are sure you have no other users, use only `-m;` This will not restrict it by client name. It allows the first admin to login, and blocks out everyone else.

Comment: No i canot login : same error message . is there any way i can check that any other service account is trying to log in ?

Comment: You can look at your eventvwr logs. Successfuly logins should show up like `Login succeeded for user`